# Binding Label's visible property in a list with Toggle switch

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mvvm

I have a toggle button and list which contains Label in it. 
Toggle(Switch) and List View are declared in Xaml file where list's Data-cell is generated programatically in cs file.
I need to hide/show this label in the list based on the toggle switch

Xaml code:

```
<Switch  IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalOptions = "Start" Margin = "10,8,8,0"></Switch>

<ListView x:Name="lvItemSigns" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Gray">
```

cs file code:

lvItemSigns.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataCell));
lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = VM.ItemSignsList;

```
class DataCell : ViewCell
{
   Label label;
   public DataCell()
   {
     // has grid
      var label = new Label();
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
            label.Margin = 4;
            label.Text = "test";
            grid.Children.Add(label, 2, 1);
            label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.IsToggled", BindingMode.TwoWay, new BooleanConverter(), null, null, "cs-file_name"));

 grid.Children.Add(stackLayout, 0, 3);

            grid.Margin = new Thickness(8,0,0,0);
            View = grid;
   }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
    public bool _IsToggled;
    public bool IsToggled
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsToggled;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsToggled= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_IsToggled");
        }
    }
public ItemSignsTabViewModel()
{
  ItemSignsList = new ObservableCollection<TicketItem>(daItemSign.GetItemSigns(Ticket.MobileID));
}
```

I'm binding the visible property to Label but still I can see the label all the time (when toggle switch is on or off).

I know I'm doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: OnPropertyChanged("_IsToggled"); - you need to use the name of the public property, not the private field

Comment: I tried this way too OnPropertyChanged("IsToggled"); did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataContext for the Switch's binding is different from you DataCell's DataContext.

Both views are not targeting the same objects. 
You need to post the code of your viewmodels for both the page, and the DataCell in order to get help.

Comment: can you check now. this is what I'm doing

Comment: When you create your bindings in your DataCell, the DataCell's BindingContext is not your "ItemSignsTabViewModel", it's an instance of TicketItem, retrieved from the ItemSignsList.
Your label binding in DataCell's code will never be created, because the property you want to use belongs to the parent DataContext.
What you need to do, is add an "IsToggled" property to your TicketItem object. Then, when ItemSignsTabViewModel.IsToggled property is set to true, update every TicketItem object of your list, to set the TicketItem.IsToggled property to ItemSignsTabViewModel.IsToggled value

Comment: Thanks @Miiite. It worked. I added a property to TicketItem object, and setting its value before OnPropertyChanged() and it worked.